# Impedance and resonance frequency of a bias tee

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, impedance, resonance, reflection

I am a beginner trying to learn about combining impedances and solving for the resonance frequency. I am solving a circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ9hTV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and I have managed to redraw in a way that is more familiar to me.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLhCRO.png)</sup>

Now I am calculating the total impedance, first for Z and C3 in parallel, and their equivalent impedance in series with L1: $$Z_{eq} = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{Z} + j \omega C_3} + j \omega L_1$$
and then finally all of them in parallel with C2:
$$Z_{total} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{Z_{eq}}+j \omega C_2}$$

than I was planning to use the formula for the reflection coefficient:

$$\Gamma =  \frac{|Z_{total}-50|}{|Z_{total} + 50|} $$ assuming 50 Ohm matching and extract the resonance frequency where it becomes 0.

I do not know how to include the remaining part of the circuit in my calculation of impedance. As far as I understand, the remaining part serves as a bias tee (it is not clear why is there a resistor R1 instead of an inductor though). Does it contribute to the resonance frequency?

Comment: Some small notes: current has to circulate: your voltage sources should have a connection at both terminals. Another note:  EE prefer using \$j\$ instead of \$i\$ because the latter is also used as current variable.

Comment: Your circuit does not look like a proper bias tee. The inductor should be used to block RF from reaching the DC source, not to block RF between the RF source and load.

Comment: Thank you @Huisman, I have applied the changes you suggested.